# "FeedItem requires a filter by Id" exception despite filtering by ID

Tags: chatter, dynamic-soql, feeditem, feedcomment

A client is getting an exception whenever they insert a FeedComment in their org.  There is a trigger on FeedComment (api 25.0) which calls a static method in a class (api 26.0) to get a list of FeedItems.

The error is:

```
ns.myAppFeedComment: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.QueryException: Implementation restriction: FeedItem requires a filter by Id

Class.myApp.myAppFeedItemsHandler.getArchivedFeedItemsIdByFeedId: line 127, column 1
Trigger.myApp.myAppFeedComment: line 60, column 1
```

Here is the query.  "tempIdSet" is the keySet of a map passed to getArchivedFeedItemsIdByFeedId as a parameter.

```
Set<Id> tempIdSet = idMap.keySet();

String query = 'Select RelatedRecordId, Id, Type, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName,'+
                                    'ParentId, Body, Title, LinkUrl, InsertedById ,'+
                                    'ContentDescription,ContentType,ContentSize, ContentData, ContentFileName, CommentCount';


 if(myAppUtils.isCommunitiesEnabled()){

    communitiesEnabled = true;
    query+=', NetworkScope';
 }

query+=' From FeedItem i where i.Id in :tempIdSet';

List<Sobject> feedItems = Database.query(query);
```

The exception is obviously occurred when the query takes place.  There are two things I don't understand.

1. I am filtering by ID.  I am querying against a list of IDs, does it want me to use a single ID and put it in a for loop?
2. Secondly, this query is made every time a FeedComment is inserted and has worked for many clients without a problem - why would it suddenly fail?  A Winter 14 bug?  It can't be API Version since that hasn't changed.

It's difficult for me to debug fully since I don't have full access to the org, but any pointers would be great.

EDIT:

I reproduced with a System.runAs in a test with a standard user.  If idMap contains `[UserInfo.getUserId(), '123'] [null, '456']`

Then I get the error.

The only problem with this hypothesis is that the map keys are populated from the `FeedComment's` `FeedItemId` in the After Insert trigger.  Since `FeedItemId` is a required field, I don't see how it can be null.

Comment: I have created a v25.0 `after insert` trigger on FeedComment and a static method in a v26.0 class containing your code, and the query seems to execute alright. Have you triple checked this query is the culprit?

Comment: @user320 See my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty unbelievable, and almost certainly a Salesforce bug.

This fails when run as a Standard Platform User:

```
Id ii = UserInfo.getUserId();

List<FeedItem> fis = [Select Id from FeedItem i where i.Id = :ii];
```

But this works:

```
Id ii = UserInfo.getUserId();

List<FeedItem> fis = [Select Id from FeedItem where Id = :ii];
```

A regular expression gone wrong?  Who knows...

I've tested up to API version 27 and the problem remains.  It may have been fixed since then, I don't know.

Comment: I think you're right about the bug, George. Salesforce docs say, "You can use alias notation in SELECT queries." If you haven't already, I think the best path to resolution is to log a case with salesforce.com and escalate this problem as a bug: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_typos.htm#kanchor3